# Hot-fix Project in Advanced Installer

Tags: project, hotfix, advanced-installer

I am new to Advanced Installer, since I am using a trial version, I want as much as I can about it. I have an installer, already created. 
One of the files it installs is **InvoicePro.exe** (version 1.0.0.0). I found some bugs in that version so I built the version 1.0.0.1 in Visual Studio. Now I want to create a Hot-fix installer to replace version 1.0.0.0 with version 1.0.0.1.

Please explain me clearly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [upgrades page](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/upgrades.html) from our user guide explains what you need to do. Just make sure you increase the version number for one of the 3 fields, otherwise Windows will not remove the old version, because it ignores changes in the forth field of the product version.

Comment: I actually need only one file (the executable) to be replaced from my installation folder, and so I treated this installer as a patch, or how you want to call it...

Comment: You can do a patch too, as explained by us in this article: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-patch.html Mainly you follow the same steps, but when you increase the product version you just answer with "Patch" instead of "Major upgrade".